# Adding position/order in array of objects

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects like below:

```
    [{
    "id": 1,
    "Size": 90,
    "Maturity": 24,
   },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Size": 85,
    "Maturity": 22,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "Size": 80,
    "Maturity": 20,
   }]
```

I need to this Array on basis of different property value sorting (eg: Maturity) and also add a column order which has the ascending order/rank.
Eg:

```
      [{
        "id": 1,
        "Size": 90,
        "Maturity": 22,
         "Order": 2
       },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "Size": 85,
        "Maturity": 25,
        "Order": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "Size": 80,
        "Maturity": 20,
        "Order": 1
       }]
```

Comment: In which language will you do that? By the way, your sample order numbering is not accurate, am I wrong?

Comment: @vahdet Edited the question. I need it in AngularJS.

Comment: The two examples have different data so it is hard to understand what you are asking. Also, you should post your code, so we can see what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "Size": 90,
    "Maturity": 24,
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "Size": 85,
    "Maturity": 22,
   },
   {
    "id": 3,
    "Size": 80,
    "Maturity": 20,
   }];

arr
  .map((item,index) => ({ ...item, Order: index + 1 }))
  .sort((a, b) => b.Maturity - a.Maturity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array with `sort` and then add prop to each object with respect to the index they are sorted on with `forEach`:

```js
var inp = [{
    id: 1,
    Size: 90,
    Maturity: 24,
   },
  {
    id: 2,
    Size: 85,
    Maturity: 22,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Size: 80,
    Maturity: 20,
   }]
   
// Sort
inp.sort(function(a, b){
  return a.Maturity == b.Maturity ? 0 : +(a.Maturity > b.Maturity) || -1;
});

// add prop
inp.forEach(function(row, index) {
  row.index = index + 1;
});

console.log(inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var objs = [ 
    {
    "id": 1,
    "Size": 90,
    "Maturity": 24,
   },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "Size": 85,
    "Maturity": 22,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "Size": 80,
    "Maturity": 20,
   }];
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.Size < b.Size)
    return -1;
  if (a.Size > b.Size)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

objs.sort(compare);
for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    objs[i].Order = i+1;
}
console.log(objs);
```